# Can Rsync get incremental on files it hasn't touched yet?

Tags: server, backup, rsync

I have an Ubuntu server which acts as a file server for a few Windows clients, using Samba. This server mirrors a couple of large directories to a support server using rsync. I need to replace the support server.

I'm building the replacement support server, and have a recent tar backup of the mirrored directories. There will be some more work completed in these directories before I can replace the support server, so my tarball will be out of date.

To save time, I'd like to unpack the archive into the correct location with all of the correct permissions and ownerships, which I already know how to do, then run the normal rsync command to just update the differences. I know I can just run rsync to move the whole lot over, but I'd like to minimise time spent on the client's site

Will this work? If not, is there another method to complete this process quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work. Look at `man rsync` and the `--update` option. If you use `-u` it will totally skip files that have a newer timestamp on the destination. If you don't use `-u` it will checksum the files and sync them if there's a difference (there will be in your case). So don't use `-u` in your rsync invocation.

Also, why not try to be empirical? Instead of just asking, why don't you try it with a smaller file? experiment!